# How to enable local LAN DNS name resolution in Windows server 2008r2?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm running a Windows 2008r2 server in a non-Domain (workgroup) role. It is a DNS server and DHCP server for the LAN.

DNS services work fine for external Internet addresses, but local hostnames do not resolve.

```
c:\>ping raspberrypi1.local
Ping request could not find host raspberrypi1.local. Please check the name and try again.

c:\batch>ping raspberrypi1
Ping request could not find host raspberrypi1. Please check the name and try again.

c:\batch>ping 192.168.1.169
Pinging 192.168.1.169 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.169: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.169: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64  .....
```

The DHCP server lists the correct hostname for all the devices on the LAN in its list of leases, but the DNS server seems to be unaware.

How do I enable local hostname resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the DHCP scope settings to get the clients to register their DNS? Or configured the client network interface settings to do their own registrations?

Also, less relevantly, but useful, do you have the reverse zones set up ready to take the PTR record registrations? Is the option to register PTR records disabled in your DHCP scope config?

The article below shows some screenshots of all these DHCP scope options, although it's not very well laid-out. You'll need to do some scrolling down to find the relevant examples, particularly for the one to configure client DNS registrations in the DHCP scope.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/teamdhcp/2014/01/26/windows-server-2012-r2-enhancing-dhcp-policies-and-dns-registrations-in-dhcp-server/

Comment: The article seems to point out new features for Windows Server 2012, but I'm running 2008r2. Does the article still apply? If so how?

Comment: Configuring client DNS options in a DHCP scope has been around since  (Windows?) DHCP has existed, including the option for clients to register their addresses in DNS. I suggest simply googling for it.

Comment: Yes, the DNS are correct as they are described in various articles. But DNS for local LAN devices does not work. So perhaps there is a more subtle issue?